# PowerShell Set/Get-ACL Special Permissions - This Folder Only setting

Tags: powershell, ntfs

I have this script which sets folder permissions:

```
Get-Acl $IGXYSimFiles 
$acl = Get-Acl $IGXYSimFiles
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($false,$true)
$rule = New-Object
System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("RISK\DL-GPA-UKI-Users","CreateFiles", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
$rule = New-Object
System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("RISK\DL-GPA-UKI-Igloo-IGXY-Power-Users","Modify", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl $IGXYSimFiles $acl
```

I need to add special permissions for the DL-GPA-UKI-Users group so that they can create subfolders in the $IGXYSimFiles folder but not files. They need to be able to create files in the subfolders which they've been allowed to create, but not any further subfolders.

I have achieved this by setting special permissions "Create Folder / Append Data" for "This Folder Only" and "Create Files / Write Data" for "Subfolders and Files Only". This is working great, but now comes the time where I need to edit my script to do this.

So I thought I would get-acl on the folder where I have manually set these permissions, this isn't returning the desired result:

> AccessToString          :
>
> RISK\DL-GPA-UKI-Igloo-IGXY-Power-Users Allow  Modify,Synchronize
>
> RISK\DL-GPA-UKI-Users Allow  AppendData, Synchronize
>
> RISK\DL-GPA-UKI-Users Allow  CreateFiles, Synchronize
>
> NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
>
> RISK\Domain Admins Allow  FullControl
>
> RISK\DL-GPA-UKI-Readonly Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
>
> RISK\svcGIECSSPrd_EA Allow  FullControl
>
> RISK\DL-GPA-UKI-Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
>
> RISK\DL-GPA-AIMSSOPS Allow  FullControl

As you can see its not displaying the "This Folder Only" or "Subfolders and files only" setting...

Is this possible with PowerShell?

Many thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. The default output for Get-Acl doesn't include the inheritance information, but it's there. Try this to get a friendlier output:

```
Get-ACL $IGXYSimFiles | % { $_.Access }
```

As for setting the ACL as desired, your script should do it, though you have one error in your rule. For "Create Files / Write Data" to be applied to "Subfolders and Files Only", you'll want to set the PropagationFlags to InheritOnly rather than None.

```
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("RISK\DL-GPA-UKI-Users","CreateFiles", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "InheritOnly", "Allow")
```

And this will set "Create Folder / Append Data" on this folder only:

```
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("RISK\DL-GPA-UKI-Users","AppendData", "None", "None", "Allow")
```

Comment: AMAZING!! thanks so much, you wont believe how long I've been trying to fix this, really appreciate your prompt and concise answer!